# Отформатировать советскую дату

Tags: html, скиллометрия, css, вёрстка

Был такой стиль форматирования дат в СССР, который сейчас можно встретить, разве что, только на надгробиях(туда ему и дорога).
Сначала первые две цифры года, потом дробью число/римскими месяц, потом вторые две цифры года.

[image]

Задача: максимально читабельно и кроссбраузерно отформатировать дату, заданную в юникс-формате. Работать должно на стандартных библиотеках.
Количество кода не волнует, очень волнуют спички, то бишь, скорость работы.

Мой вариант.
Не нравится, что не отслеживается ширина числа дней. Отсюда неидеальное выравнивание:

```
function rus1960($time){
  $year = date('Y',$time);
  $month = rome(date('n',$time));
  $day = date('j',$time);
  $year = str_split($year,2);
  $day = '<span style="font-size: 0.5em; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: top">'.$day.'</span>';
  $month = '<span style="font-size: 0.5em; margin-left: -1.1em;">'.$month.'</span>';
  return $year[0].$day.$month.$year[1];
}

function rome($N){
  $c='IVXLCDM';
  for($a=5,$b=$s='';$N;$b++,$a^=7)
    for($o=$N%$a,$N=$N/$a^0;$o--;$s=$c[$o>2?$b+$N-($N&=-2)+$o=1:$b].$s);
      return $s;
}
```

P.S. Заодно представляю новый тэг

Comment: интересно, что google не знает такого слова.

Comment: Какого слова? Скиллометрия? =) Ну не буду же я на приличном форуме писать "фа**ометрия", верно? Skill - умение, навык

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
$rome = array('', 'I',  'II',  'III',  'IV',  'V',  'VI',  'VII',  'VIII',  'IX',  'X',  'XI', 'XII');
$year = date('Y');
$month = (int) date('n');
$day = date('j');
?>
<span style="line-height:200%">
    <?=$year[0].$year[1]?>
    <span style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;line-height:100%;vertical-align:middle">
        <div style="text-decoration:underline"><?=$day?></div>
        <?=$rome[$month]?>
    </span>
    <?=$year[2].$year[3]?>
</span>
```

Нет лишних вызовов функций и обсчетов. CSS форматируйте как вам надо.

Comment: Насчет римских месяцев - 10 баллов. =)
А в HTML смущает Inline-block. У IE с ним проблемы, не?

Comment: По отношению к span'ам проблем нет - проблемы только с блочными элементами. Проверьте).

Comment: Ага, все чётко. =)

Answer (score 2):

Изображение:

```
<table>
  <tr valign = 'center' align = 'center'>
    <td rowspan = 2>20</td>
    <td style = 'border-bottom:1px solid black;'>4</td>
    <td rowspan = 2>06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign = 'center' align = 'center'>
    <td>V</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Алгоритм перевода в римские цифры ( JS ):

```
function rome( num ){
  var d4 = [ '', 'M', 'MM', 'MMM' ],
      d3 = [ '', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CD', 'D', 'DC', 'DCC', 'DCCC', 'CM'  ],
      d2 = [ '', 'X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC' ],
      d1 = [ '', 'I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX' ];

  return  d4[ num /10000 % 1000 ] +
          d3[ num /1000 % 100 ] +
          d2[ num /100 % 10 ] +
          d1[ num %10 ];
}
```

P.S: Каноническое представление чисел больше 3999 в римскими цифрами - невозможно

Comment: О, вот это мне уже нравится, хотя и смущает использование таблицы. =/ Чего-то во мне чесаться начинает при мысли об инлайновой таблице...